# Brainfuck Interpreter

Tags: haskell, brainfuck, interpreter

I want to write an example for a language similar to Haskell called [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege/). While the interpreter is conceptually easy, it is lengthy and looks still quite messy. Note that I **don't** want to use Parsec etc, as it isn't available yet in Frege. Please help me to improve the Haskell version.

```
import Data.Char

data Tape = Tape { left :: [Int], cell :: Int, right :: [Int] }

instance Show Tape where
   show (Tape ls c rs) = show [reverse ls,[c],rs]

data Op = Plus | Minus | GoLeft | GoRight | Output | Input | Loop [Op] deriving (Eq, Show)

removeComments :: [Char] -> [Char]
removeComments xs = filter (`elem` "+-<>.,[]") xs

parseOp :: [Char] -> Maybe (Op, [Char])
parseOp ('+':cs) = Just (Plus, cs)
parseOp ('-':cs) = Just (Minus, cs)
parseOp ('<':cs) = Just (GoLeft, cs)
parseOp ('>':cs) = Just (GoRight, cs)
parseOp ('.':cs) = Just (Output, cs)
parseOp (',':cs) = Just (Input, cs)
parseOp ('[':cs) = case parseOps cs of
  (prog, (']':cs')) -> Just (Loop prog, cs')
  _ -> Nothing
parseOp _ = Nothing

parseOps :: [Char] -> ([Op],[Char])
parseOps cs = go cs [] where
  go cs acc = case parseOp cs of
    Nothing -> (reverse acc, cs)
    Just (op, cs') -> go cs' (op:acc)

parse :: String -> [Op]
parse prog = case parseOps $ removeComments $ prog of
   (ops, []) -> ops
   (ops, rest) -> error $ "Parsed: " ++ show ops ++ ", Rest: " ++ rest

execute :: [Op] -> IO Tape
execute prog = exec prog (Tape [] 0 [])

exec :: [Op] -> Tape -> IO Tape
exec [] tape = return tape
exec (Plus:prog) (Tape ls c rs) = exec prog (Tape ls (c+1) rs)
exec (Minus:prog) (Tape ls c rs) = exec prog (Tape ls (c-1) rs)
exec (GoLeft:prog) (Tape ls c rs) =
  let (hd,tl) = uncons ls in exec prog (Tape tl hd (c:rs))
exec (GoRight:prog) (Tape ls c rs) =
  let (hd,tl) = uncons rs in exec prog (Tape (c:ls) hd tl)
exec (Output:prog) tape = do
  printAsChar (cell tape)
  exec prog tape
exec (Input:prog) (Tape ls _ rs) = do
  n <- getChar
  exec prog (Tape ls (digitToInt n) rs)
exec (Loop loop:prog) tape @ (Tape ls 0 rs) = exec prog tape
exec again@(Loop loop:prog) tape = do
  tape' <- exec loop tape
  exec (if (cell tape') == 0 then prog else again) tape'

uncons :: [Int] -> (Int,[Int])
uncons [] = (0,[])
uncons (x:xs) = (x,xs)


printAsChar :: Int -> IO ()
printAsChar i = putStr $ [chr i]

main = do
  tape <- execute $ parse helloWorld
  putStrLn $ "\n" ++ show tape ++ "\n"

helloWorld =
  ">+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>+++++++[<++++>-]<+.+++++++..+++.[-]>++++++++" ++
  "[<++++>-]<.>+++++++++++[<+++++>-]<.>++++++++[<+++>-]<.+++.------.--------." ++
  "[-]>++++++++[<++++>-]<+.[-]++++++++++."
```

**[Edit]**

parseOp can be simplified to:

```
ops = [('+', Plus),('-', Minus),('<',GoLeft),('>',GoRight),('.',Output),(',',Input)]

parseOp :: [Char] -> Maybe (Op, [Char])
parseOp ('[':cs) = case parseOps cs of
  (prog, (']':cs')) -> Just (Loop prog, cs')
  _ -> Nothing
parseOp (c:cs) = fmap (flip (,) cs) $ lookup c ops
parseOp [] = Nothing
```

Comment: This is about as straightforward as it gets. You could line some things up with whitespace, and perhaps use `where` instead of `let/in`, but other than that, there's really not much I can see that could be simplified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about Frege, all comments apply to Haskell only.

1)

Running [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) on your code shows places where you can remove `$` and brackets. Please do it!

2)

In `exec`, you always do `exec prog tape` after finishing current instruction. So you are iterating the list in some sense. This is a fold.

```
exec :: [Op] -> Tape -> IO Tape
exec prog tape = foldM f tape prog

  where f (Tape ls c rs) Plus    = return $ Tape ls (c+1) rs
        f (Tape ls c rs) Minus   = return $ Tape ls (c-1) rs
        f (Tape ls c rs) GoLeft  = let (hd, tl) = uncons ls in return $ Tape tl hd (c:rs)
        f (Tape ls c rs) GoRight = let (hd, tl) = uncons rs in return $ Tape (c:ls) hd tl
        f tape           Output  = printAsChar (cell tape) >> return tape
        f (Tape ls _ rs) Input   = do n <- getChar
                                      return $ Tape ls (digitToInt n) rs

        f tape again@(Loop loop) | cell tape == 0 -> return tape
                                 | otherwise -> do tape' <- exec loop tape
                                                   f tape' again
```

3)

```
printAsChar i = putStr $ [chr i]
```

hlint will tell you the $ is redundant:

```
printAsChar i = putStr [chr i]
```

You can use `putChar`:

```
printAsChar i = putChar (chr i)
```

and finally get:

```
printAsChar =  putChar . chr
```

You have a strange asymmetry - output uses `chr`, and input `digitToInt`. These are not inverses! `digitToInt '0'` is `0`, but `chr 0` is `'\NUL'`, not `'0'`.

If you want to output numbers longer than 1 character, use

```
printAsString = putStr . show
```

4)

I would merge `execute` and `exec`:

```
 execute :: [Op] -> IO Tape
 execute = foldM f (Tape [] 0 [])
   where f = ...
```

5)

```
 putStrLn $ "\n" ++ show tape ++ "\n"
```

`putStrLn` already adds `'\n"` to the end, you might remove it.

6)

If you remove the requirement to print the tape (is it needed for debugging only?), you can use an infinite list:

```
 execute = foldM f (Tape (repeat 0) 0 (repeat 0))
```

and get rid of `uncons`:

```
       f (Tape (hd:tl) c rs) GoLeft  = return $ Tape tl hd (c:rs)
       f (Tape ls c (hd:tl)) GoRight = return $ Tape (c:ls) hd tl
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Regarding 6), I considered it, but reverted it exactly because of the debugging problem.

Comment: You could put `show (Tape ls c rs) = show [reverse (take 10 ls),[c],take 10 rs]` but I understand it might hinder debugging.